# vim tabular plugin question

Tags: vim, tabular

Before

```
@stallone = Factory :user, :name => 'Sylvester', :age => 64
@schwarzenegger = Factory :user, :name => 'Arnold', :age => 63
```

Some magic...

After

```
@stallone       = Factory :user, :name => 'Sylvester', :age => 64
@schwarzenegger = Factory :user, :name => 'Arnold',    :age => 63
```

How to make such alignment with tabular plugin for VIM?

Comment: Actually, I know how to make it in two commands :Tab / = /l0 and :Tab / :/l0. But do you know how to do this with one command? And more interesting - how to do this automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know [Tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) ([looks](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/aligning-text-with-tabular-vim/) pretty neat), but it seems cutalion has the solution.

Just map that to something:

```
map <Leader>a :Tab / = /l0<CR>:Tab / :/l0<CR>
```

If you needed to do some selectiong, add `gv` (reselect last selection) as appropriate.