# Tabular.vim : how to align on the first occurrence of 2 different delimiters placed at the beginning of Words?

Tags: vim, tabular

I have installed the Tabular plugin, which works very well for me, as long as there are no complicated regexes involved…

But I have this list :

```
one @abc @rstuvw &foo  
three @defg &bar 
four @mn @opq &kludge &hack  
twelve @hijkl &baz &quux
```

I wish to align it that way (on @… first, then on &…) :

```
one    @abc @rstuvw &foo  
three  @defg        &bar 
four   @mn @opq     &kludge &hack  
twelve @hijkl       &baz &quux
```

which means I have 3 problems at the same time :

- align on the first occurrence
- of 2 different delimiters (@ and &)
- which are not really delimiters but "special characters" at the beginning of Words

This is far beyond my understanding of both regexes and Tabular.vim

How should I proceed ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Align on the first occurrence

[The help file](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular/blob/master/doc/Tabular.txt#L133) explains this problem, you can use this command:

```
:Tabularize /^[^@]*\zs@/l1l0
```

A little explaination:

- `^` means the begin of the line
- `[^@]*` match everything that isn't a `@`. The `*` means 0 or more times, as much as you can
- `\zs` put the start of the regex here (everything from this point is matched)
- `@` the 'this point' in the previous sentence means the `@` symbol
- `/l1l0` means align the 1st block to the left and add 1 space (`l1`) and align the 2nd block to the left and add 0 spaces (`l0`)

#### Align 2 different delimiters

You need to do this in 2 commands. To make your life easier you can [name the pattern](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular/blob/master/doc/Tabular.txt#L153) and use that name:

```
:AddTabularPattern f_at /^[^@]*\zs@/l1l0
:AddTabularPattern f_and /^[^&]*\zs&/l1l0
```

Now you can run

```
:Tabularize f_at
:Tabularize f_and
```

#### Map the commands

You can even map these methods to generate easy shortcuts. Read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4743029/1149495)

Comment: It works ! Thank you very much. [NB : I simply noticed that if one instance of a pattern is missing (e.g. if &bar is missing after three @defg), the whole pattern is not aligned]. Thanks again.

Comment: Just to show that it can be done in one command: `:Tabularize/@[^&]*\|&.*/l1l0`