# How to align a Rails routes file with tabular?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, vim

I want to align this snippet from a Rails routes file from this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'about' => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'help' => 'static_pages#help'
  get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get 'signup' => 'users#new'
  get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
  post 'login' => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
end
```

To this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get    'about'   => 'static_pages#about'
  get    'help'    => 'static_pages#help'
  get    'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get    'signup'  => 'users#new'
  get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
  post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'
end
```

By using the [tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) plugin for vim.

I've been trying all kinds of regexes but can't seem to nail it.
`:Tabularize/'[^=]*\|=.*/l1l0` just mangles the texts.

The closest resource I can find is this question:
[Tabular.vim : how to align on the first occurrence of 2 different delimiters placed at the beginning of Words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330486/tabular-vim-how-to-align-on-the-first-occurrence-of-2-different-delimiters-pla)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
:Tabularize/'[^']*'\|=>/l1l0
```

The idea is to use the strings and the hash rocket as delimiters.

I recommend you read all of `:h tabular`.

Although I have not tired [vim-easy-align](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align), I have heard that it makes some alignments easier than Tabular. It might be worth checking out.

Comment: This one almost gets it done. Except for the last line which reads `delete'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'`.

Comment: I have switched the flags to accommodate this

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember how you'd do it with Tabular but:

```
:%!column -t|sed 's/  \([^ ]\)/ \1/g'
```

or:

```
:%!column -t<CR>
:%s/  \([^ ]\)/ \1/g<CR>
```

Comment: These snippets do the job but also make the lines lose their indentation. Any suggestions on how to deal with this problem that doesn't involve re-indenting the file afterwards?

Comment: Just edited the question to take into account line indentation.