# tabular.vim match first occurrence of delimeter but don't align it

Tags: vim, vim-tabular

I want to use [Tabular.vim](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) to align a Ruby shorthand hash. This requires matching the first colon but not aligning it.

```
#from
foo: bar
bazz: grault
a: b
#to
foo:  bar
bazz: grault
a:    b
```

Using the `\zs` atom as `/:\zs` gives the desired result. My understanding is that `\zs` starts the match at that position.

If I use `/^[^:]*\zs` to match the first `:` I lose the effect that `\zs` had in the first example. I'd like to understand why and get my desired alignment.

```
#from
foo: bar[:bar]
bazz: grault[:grault]
a: a[:a]
#to
foo:  bar[:bar]
bazz: grault[:grault]
a:    a[:a]
```

This [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330486/tabular-vim-how-to-align-on-the-first-occurrence-of-2-different-delimiters-pla) got me part of the way there, but matching the first colon seems to lose the effect of the `/zs` atom.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, but if someone else can answer more eloquently or descriptively, please do.

I wasn't actually matching the colon, I was matching everything up to the colon with `[^:]`. The `\zs` atom was doing what it was supposed to do.

```
:Tab /^[^:]*:
```

Comment: `[^:]` matches anything that isn't a colon. So you were matching everything from the start of the line that isn't a colon.

Comment: In case it's not obvious, my regex skills are poor. I realized this only after using a regex tester. Do you have a suggestion to improve the regex I'm using in the answer?

Comment: The `\zs` is not needed and you don't need to escape the colon. So `^[^:]*:` should be sufficient.

Comment: `:Tab /^[^:]*:` The leading slash tells Tabular it is a regex but isn't really part of the regex. (It seems to work for me...)